# How does the List interface store data in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, interface

i've been wondering how does the interface List in java store data. An interface is a set of methods that must be implemented by a class (please correct if i'm wrong) and thus a list can't have variables to store data.
For instance, `List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); list1.add(5);`
where will the integer 5 be stored ? Does the list1 use the ArrayList's attributes  to store data ? What really happens when i create an interface ? Does it create an object of a certain class to operate on it ?
Thank you

Comment: Read the ArrayList class

Comment: As you already noticed, the `List` interface can not store data. But the `ArrayList` can and stores the data in an array. A `LinkedList` stores that information as linked list. But you can use both of them interchangeable when you only use the `List` interface.

Comment: Interfaces need an implementation chosen.